# What is the right way to operate on a newly created MySQL DB within Java Play Framework (2.5.x)?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, playframework

I have already created the DB which has no tables so far & have successfully connected it with Play. But what is the right way to create the tables from within Play? I was going to proceed with Evolutions script but their documentation mentions that evolutions is to be used while updating the DB.

In Django I have seen people defining their tables in a models file. Is there any similar mechanism in Play. If so, how?
Does JPA have anything to do with all this? Again, I have read their documentation on this. It explains it in connection with Hibernate. Is an ORM layer absolutely necessary? Help me out here!

Comment: *"It explains it in connection with Ebean ORM. But I want to use MySQL."* - that statement makes no sense. EBean is an alternative to JPA. You use it to do things and stuff with MySQL or any other popular database. You should still proceed with Evolutions.

Comment: It should have been Hibernate. I got confused as I am new to these concepts. So if I use evolutions, should I create the tables on 1.sql? My concern is that the documentation suggests future updates to an existing database should be on evolutions script (either creating or altering tables). So is the workflow same when I create tables for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

So a user answered this question and then removed it. Nevertheless he suggested to use Ebean which manages the database through evolutions.

The github link posted was: https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean-example
It cleared up a few things and if someone faces the same problem, I hope this helps.

Comment: I deleted my answer because you changed the question, the answer wasn't relevant anymore.